# SQL Server AlwaysOn ReadOnly Routing to Secondary

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

I configured SQL Server AlwaysOn to redirect Read-Only to Secondary and tried to check with `ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly` setting in SSMS by connecting to the Listener. But my connection is always going to Primary only as revealed by

```
SELECT @@SERVERNAME
```

Does anyone know what is wrong with the settings or reason for this? 
I checked altering the settings but didn't work.

**Setup Details:**

> SQL Server 2017
>   AG Properties
>   Using Admin account to test the routing.

[image: AO AG Properties]

Comment: Have you specified the database you're connecting to? AG connections resolve at the DB level, not the server level.

Comment: @George.Palacios Thank you! It worked by mentioning "Initial Catalog" parameter along with ApplicationIntent. Further, I updated my Login's Default DB to point to one of AG Databases and then without "Initial Catalog" parameter also, my Reads were routed to Secondary Replica. --In 'thoughts'...

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know what is wrong with the settings or reason for this? I checked altering the settings but didn't work.

You may verify the read-only routing configuration based on [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/245389/185080)

Once all set (upon validation): If you're using SQL Login, try to mention default database that is part of AG, then your connection must be re-direct to secondary replica.

or mention following parameter from SSMS connection. This is how usually every application connects.

```
ApplicationIntent=READONLY; Initial Catalog=YourDatabase
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked by mentioning "Initial Catalog" parameter along with ApplicationIntent. Further, I updated my Login's Default DB to point to one of AG Databases and then without "Initial Catalog" parameter also, my Reads were routed to Secondary Replica. --In 'thoughts'...